# Onclick function not working within <span>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using an onclick function to drop down a simple list on my mobile site, but it's not working - code is below. The strange thing is that I have something else formatted exactly the same right next to it, and that works fine (everything named differently, of course).

Obviously the "show3" class isn't getting toggled, since I can change the "display: none;" to "display: block" in .incoming-listc and it shows up fine. However, when I click on the "Incoming" span, nothing happens!

HTML:

```
<div class="mobile-incoming">
<span onclick="myFunction3()">Incoming <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
<div id="incoming-list" class="incoming-listc">
    Updated 5.4.16<br>Goodall RCJ EIR/Adirondack<br>2008 Martin 000-18 Authentic
</div>
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction3() {
        document.getElementById("incoming-list").classList.toggle("show3");
    }
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.mobile-incoming {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 60px;
cursor: pointer;
text-align: right;
line-height: 44px;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Verdana;
font-size: 0.8em;
font-weight: 200;
color: white;
}

.incoming-listc {
display: none;
position: fixed;
top: 45px;
right: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.9);
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.show3 {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: `.toggle()` is a jQuery function.  Is jQuery loaded here?

Comment: Even if jQuery is loaded it will not work, because toggle is executed not on jQuery element.

Comment: But it is not jQuery function: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp

Comment: maybe you're testing it on IE. It is not supported on IE

Comment: It works in IE 10, but not on IE 9 and lower

Comment: I've just tried it and it works, maybe you're using an old browser as Asaf suggested.

Comment: I also tested in FF, via SO's snippets and it worked fine. I did have to change the color away from white at first so I knew what I was clicking on.

Comment: I've tried it and it works [JsFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/a1zv9sLo/)

Comment: Well, I have an identical construct just above this one, only it has different ID and class names. Exactly same concept though - and it works fine. This is on Safari 9. Seems to work fine in the JsFiddle posted by Shady.

So obviously some other code on my page is conflicting with it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out. Just in case anyone finds this later with a similar problem. My CSS was actually in a different order in my stylesheet than what I pasted to you guys. Once I put the "show3" class after the other two classes, it magically started working. Had no idea the order of the classes mattered!

Comment: CSS order absolutely matters! Check out this guide on "the cascade," it may help you better understand how CSS is "parsed" by browsers: http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/getting-to-know-css/